# Attempt to present which is already presenting - Stripe SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, stripe-payments

I am trying to create an app with Stripe Checkout following the tutorials here:

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide?platform=ios

https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic#set-up-ephemeral-key-client-side

I am having issues when setting up the `STPPaymentContext` hosting view controller.

The `PaymentView` is presented as a `.sheet`

```
paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: customerContext, configuration: config, theme: .defaultTheme)

paymentContext.delegate = paymentContextDelegate
    
    let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
        .filter({$0.activationState == .foregroundActive})
        .map({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
        .compactMap({$0})
        .first?.windows
        .filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first
    
paymentContext.hostViewController = keyWindow?.rootViewController
```

This presents the following error.

> Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x10b2a9a00> on
> <*TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier*_:
> 0x10a810f90> (from
> <*TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier*_:
> 0x10a810f90>) which is already presenting
> <*TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView*:

**Full Code:**

```
import SwiftUI
import Stripe

struct PaymentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
    @State private var paymentContext: STPPaymentContext!
    let config = STPPaymentConfiguration.shared

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            CheckoutView()
        }.onAppear {
             paymentContextConfiguration()
        }
    }

func pay() {
    self.paymentContext.requestPayment()
}

func paymentContextConfiguration() {
    let customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: MyAPIClient(customerID: self.model.profile!.stripeCustomerID!))
    
    config.requiredBillingAddressFields = .none
    config.requiredShippingAddressFields = .none
    
    let paymentContextDelegate = PaymentContextDelegate()

    paymentContextDelegate.accountID = model.accountID
    paymentContextDelegate.fee = model.fee
    paymentContextDelegate.card = model.card
    paymentContextDelegate.amount = model.amount
    paymentContextDelegate.currency = model.currency
    
    paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: customerContext, configuration: config, theme: .defaultTheme)

    paymentContext.delegate = paymentContextDelegate
    
    let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
        .filter({$0.activationState == .foregroundActive})
        .map({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
        .compactMap({$0})
        .first?.windows
        .filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first
    
    paymentContext.hostViewController = keyWindow?.rootViewController

}

}
```

Comment: I see you haven't got an answer yet - and I unfortunately don't have one for you - so you might want to reach out to Support directly with this: https://support.stripe.com/contact/email